# option<int> vs int option

Tags: f#, type-providers

When I declare a member of type `int option` like this:

```
type T = {
    X : int option
}
```

or like this:

```
type T = {
    X : option<int>
}
```

when I hover on `X` the type tooltip says `int option`

When a erased propery is generated on a type provider, the tooltip says `Option<int>`.
The type is being created like this on the type provider: `typedefof<option<_>>.MakeGenericType [| typeof<int> |]`

Can I create it in any other way so the tooltip says `int option`?

PS: I'm using here `int` as an example, so I can't just do `typeof<int option>`, as the type wrapper by the option could be anything.

Comment: They're aliases, i.e. identical aside from (subjective) readability.

Comment: Why do you want to change what the tooltip shows?

Comment: It annoys me slightly that the tooltips of the generated members of my type provider behave differently of the tooltips of manually created types. And on top of that it's not even showing `option<T>`, it's showing `Option<T>`. `T option` is nicer IMHO. I'm also curious for what triggers these different behaviours

Comment: The tooltip comments will be different as the tokenizer will parse the line and different tokens will be built based on finding `int option` and `Option<int>` in the token stream.

Comment: If your really interested in that you can see some of the code in the open source implementation: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/vs/service.fs#L1058`

Comment: The weird thing is, that the tooltip will always show `int option` regardless of me using `int option` or `option<int>`, so it's not just the tokenizer. I guess I would have to attach the debuuger to the compiler to figure out the difference

Comment: My guess is that the TypeProvider version is grabbing the documentation in a different way.  If you have a small snipped then I could trace it for you.

Comment: `let csv = new CsvProvider<"a,b\n1,2", Schema="float option,float option">()\nlet row = csv.Data |> Seq.head`. The tooltip of `row.a` shows this

Comment: Using `typedefof<_ option>.MakeGenericType [| typeof<int> |]` instead also doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your own code is being run through a method that tidies up type names and displays them in a more friendly way (possibly [`FormatItemDescriptionToDataTipElement`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/19507b98bc6a7995e9c19c40f044fdfeb578ef77/src/fsharp/vs/ServiceDeclarations.fs#L615)?), but the Type Provider is just providing raw info, and hasn't been routed through a nice display function.